# Validate email addresses using Regex

Tags: regex, email-validation

I have a regex for my email validation which is:

```
^(?!.*\.{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_\.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+
```

I need to be able to prevent the user from entering the below email addresses :

.email@example.com

email.@example.com

email@example.com (Joe Smith)

email@-example.com

email@111.222.333.44444

How do I modify my existing regex so that it handles the above email addresses?

Comment: That's not email validation, you're presenting email restriction.

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be just to add them conditions into your RegEx

```
^[^\.][a-zA-Z0-9_\.+-]+[^\.]@[^-][a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/dD8azG/1

Comment: This is matching `§............#@?------------..............` not sure it's a valid email.

Comment: fit to their condition of solving their criteria, I assumed they didn't want an out the box regex for email addresses?

Comment: For example, they don't want to match 2 consecutive dots, your regex does. see: https://regex101.com/r/dD8azG/2

Answer (score 0):

This regex seems to be working fine.

^(?!.*.{2})[^<>()[]\,.;:\%#^\s@\"$&!@]+@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$